# provider.credential' is undefined in Expo Firebase Google authentication

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo, google-authentication

I'm very new and trying to set Firebase Google authentication in Expo RN app,

Expo docs code snippet below:

https://docs.expo.dev/guides/authentication/#google

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import { ResponseType } from 'expo-auth-session';
import * as Google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithCredential } from 'firebase/auth';
import { Button } from 'react-native';

// Initialize Firebase
initializeApp({
  /* Config */
});

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

export default function App() {

  const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useIdTokenAuthRequest(
    {
      clientId: 'Your-Web-Client-ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      },
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (response?.type === 'success') {
      const { id_token } = response.params;
      
      const auth = getAuth();
      const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
      const credential = provider.credential(id_token);
      signInWithCredential(auth, credential);
    }
  }, [response]);

  return (
    <Button
      disabled={!request}
      title="Login"
      onPress={() => {
        promptAsync();
        }}
    />
  );
}
```

I'm getting error something like that:

```
TypeError: provider.credential is not a function. (In 'provider.credential(_id_token)', 'provider.credential' is undefined)
```

Any solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace the following code:

```
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
const credential = provider.credential(id_token);
```

with:

```
const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);
```

I believe the expo docs need to be updated to reflect this.